# Searching for UUIDs in text with regex

Tags: regex

I'm searching for UUIDs in blocks of text using a regex. Currently I'm relying on the assumption that all UUIDs will follow a patttern of 8-4-4-4-12 hexadecimal digits.

Can anyone think of a use case where this assumption would be invalid and would cause me to miss some UUIDs?

Comment: This question from 6 years ago was to help me with a project to find credit cards in a block of text. I've subsequently open sourced the code which is linked from my blog post which explains the nuance that the UUIDs were causing when searching for credit cards http://www.guyellisrocks.com/2013/11/parsing-text-for-credit-card-number.html

Comment: A search for UUID regular expression pattern matching brought me to this stack overflow post but the accepted answer actually isn't an answer. Additionally, the link you provided in the comment below your question also doesn't have the pattern (unless I'm missing something). Is one of these answer something you ended up using?

Comment: If you follow the rabbit warren of links starting with the one that I posted you might come across this line in GitHub which has the regex that I finally used. (Understandable that it is difficult to find.) That code and that file might help you: https://github.com/guyellis/CreditCard/blob/master/Company.CreditCard/CreditCard.cs#L98

Comment: None of these answers seem to give a single regex for all variants of only valid RFC 4122 UUIDs. But it looks like such an answer was given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13653180/421049

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I agree that by definition your regex does not miss any UUID. However it may be useful to note that if you are searching especially for Microsoft's Globally Unique Identifiers (GUIDs), there are five equivalent string representations for a GUID:

```
"ca761232ed4211cebacd00aa0057b223" 

"CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223" 

"{CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223}" 

"(CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223)" 

"{0xCA761232, 0xED42, 0x11CE, {0xBA, 0xCD, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x57, 0xB2, 0x23}}"
```

Comment: Under what situations would the first pattern be found? i.e. Is there a .Net function that would strip the hyphens or return the GUID without hyphens?

Comment: You can get it with myGuid.ToString("N").

Answer (score 702):

The regex for uuid is:

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

If you want to enforce the full string to match this regex, you will sometimes (your matcher API may have a method) need to surround above expression with `^...$`, that is

```
^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$
```

Comment: In some cases you might even want to make that [a-fA-F0-9] or [A-F0-9].

Comment: +1 for pattern, but I'm wondering [0-9a-f] might perform better as more random hex digits will be a number instead of alphabetic character?

Comment: @cyber-monk: [0-9a-f] is identical to [a-f0-9] and [0123456789abcdef] in meaning and in speed, since the regex is turned into a state machine anyway, with each hex digit turned into an entry in a state-table. For an entry point into how this works, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton

Comment: @JesperSM indeed [0-9a-f] ~ [a-f0-9] but [0123456789abcdef] is ~1% slower probably because there's more "string" to get parsed. The setup: `timeit.timeit(stmt="re.match('[0123456789abcdef]{8}-[0123456789abcdef]{4}-[0123456789abcdef]{4}-[0123456789abcdef]{4}-[0123456789abcdef]{12}$','82b1510f-d735-4952-8a6d-0f7d6bfe7960')",setup='import re', number=100000)/timeit.timeit(stmt="re.match('[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$','82b1510f-d735-4952-8a6d-0f7d6bfe7960')",setup='import re', number=100000)`

Comment: This solution is not quite correct.  It matches IDs that have invalid version and variant characters per RFC4122. @Gajus' solution is more correct in that regard. Also, the RFC allows upper-case characters on input, so adding [A-F] would be appropriate.

Comment: @broofa, I see that you are really set on everyone matching only UUIDs that are consistent with the RFC. However, I think the fact that you have had to point this out so many times is a solid indicator that not all UUIDs will use the RFC version and variant indicators. The UUID definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Definition states a simple 8-4-4-4-12 pattern and 2^128 possibilities. The RFC represents only a subset of that. So what do you want to match? The subset, or all of them?

Comment: @RichardBronosky - A fair point.  I guess it's not really clear from the OP's question whether or not RFC-compliance is an important distinction.  (although his concern is more with false negatives so perhaps it's not.)  Pick your poison, I suppose. :/

Comment: You can compress this regex quite a bit: `[0-9a-f]{8}-(?:[0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}`.

Comment: @AndrewCoad The internal `\b`'s are unnecessary, and if you care about boundaries at the ends of the UUID then the outer `\b`'s should probably be replaced with `^..$` (or `\A..\z` if you're in Ruby). Depending on language, the `/i` switch removes the need for specifying both `a-z` and `A-F`. In summary: `/^[0-9a-f]{8}-(?:[0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}$/i`. Even this is incorrect though, because it allows invalid UUIDs through. See answer from @Gajus below.

Comment: @Dr.Hans-PeterStörr in fact, you can handle the cases with the` \i` flag without `[a-fA-F0-9]` check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ef77886e4a59).

Answer (score 174):

@ivelin: UUID can have capitals. So you'll either need to toLowerCase() the string or use:

`[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}`

Would have just commented this but not enough rep :)

Comment: Usually you can handle this by defining the pattern as case insensitive with an i after the pattern, this makes a cleaner pattern:

/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/i

Comment: @ThomasBindzus That option isn't available in all languages. The original pattern in this answer worked for me in Go. The `/.../i` version didn't.

Comment: For future readers: `/i` is not the only way. Go (and not only) supports "(?i)" at the beginning of the pattern, like `(?i)[a-f0-9]....` , which would also make the whole pattern case insensitive. `(?i)` makes everything to the right side case-insensitive. Counterpart `(?-i)`.

Comment: @ChrisRedford works on most regex engine check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ef77886e4a59).

Answer (score 147):

If you want to check or validate **a specific UUID version**, here are the corresponding regexes.

> Note that **the only difference is the version number**, which is explained in `4.1.3. Version` chapter of [UUID 4122 RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

The version number is the first character of the third group : `[VERSION_NUMBER][0-9A-F]{3}` :

- UUID v1 :

  ```
  /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[1][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i
  ```
- UUID v2 :

  ```
  /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[2][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i
  ```
- UUID v3 :

  ```
  /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[3][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i
  ```
- UUID v4 :

  ```
  /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[4][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i
  ```
- UUID v5 :

  ```
  /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[5][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i
  ```

Comment: The patterns do not include lower case letters. It should also contain `a-f` next to each `A-F` scope.

Comment: The `i` at the end of the regex marks it as case insensitive.

Comment: A pattern modifier cannot always be used. For example, in a openapi definition, the pattern is case sensitive

Comment: @StephaneJanicaud In OpenAPI, you should rather use the `format` modifier by setting it to "uuid" instead of using a regex to test UUIDs: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#format

Comment: Thank you @IvanGabriele for the tip, it was just an example,it's the same problem when you wan't to check any case insensitive pattern.

Answer (score 143):

> Version 4 UUIDs have the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B. e.g. f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479.

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Definition

Therefore, this is technically more correct:

```
/[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}/
```

Comment: I don't think you mean a-z.

Comment: Need to accept [A-F], too.  Per section 3 of RFC4122: 'The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as lower case characters **and are case insensitive on input**'.  Also `(:?8|9|A|B)` is probably slightly more readable as `[89aAbB]`

Comment: Need to copy @broofa's modification; as yours excludes lower-case A or B.

Comment: @elliottcable Depending on your environment, just use `i` (case-insensitive) flag.

Comment: You're rejecting Version 1 to 3 and 5. Why?

Comment: this regex fails for - 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440001 since it's valid.

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan right this is only for version 4 which iGEL mentioned, but you've got a v1 UUID. I think the only difference between UUIDs are the version numbers in the third group (i.e. `4[a-f0-9]{3}`). I got that from Ivan's answer.

Comment: @prostýčlověk  check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/3de5d503149c) works fine for your UUID string.

Answer (score 43):

```
/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89AB][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i
```

Gajus' regexp rejects UUID V1-3 and 5, even though they are valid.

Comment: But it allows invalid versions (like 8 or A) and invalid variants.

Comment: Note that AB in [89AB][0-9a-f] is upper case and the rest of allowed characters are lower case. It has caught me out in Python

Comment: but it reject UUID version 4, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/50743d93f77e).

Comment: @AmineKOUIS You didn't make the regex case-insensitive (See the `/i` at the end). So the `[89AB]` doesn't match.

Answer (score 23):

`[\w]{8}(-[\w]{4}){3}-[\w]{12}` has worked for me in most cases.

Or if you want to be really specific `[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}`.

Comment: It it worth noting that \w, in Java at least, matches _ as well as hexadecimal digits. Replacing the \w with \p{XDigit} may be more appropriate as that is the POSIX class defined for matching hexadecimal digits. This may break when using other Unicode charsets tho.

Comment: @oconnor `\w` usually means "word characters" It will match much more than hex-digits. Your solution is much better. Or, for compatibility/readability you could use `[a-f0-9]`

Comment: Here is a string that looks like a regex and match those patterns, but is an invalid regex: 2wtu37k5-q174-4418-2cu2-276e4j82sv19

Comment: @OleTraveler not true, works like a charm. `import re

def valid_uuid(uuid):
    regex = re.compile('[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}', re.I)
    match = regex.match(uuid)
    return bool(match)

valid_uuid('2wtu37k5-q174-4418-2cu2-276e4j82sv19')`

Comment: @tom That string (2wt...) is an invalid UUID, but the pattern given in this answer matches that string indicating falsely that it is a valid UUID.  It's too bad I don't remember why that UUID is invalid.

Comment: @OleTraveler That's interesting. I don't know much about UUIDs in general but my UUIDs were generated by the [UUID 4 generator](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/) and it matches what [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format).  
  EDIT: I read again what you wrote. I may understand what you mean, this code just counts the number of characters but UUID also consists of version and variant within itself. For me this code is sufficient, but indeed there are cases where invalid UUID will match this pattern. Thanks for contributing to the discussion.

Answer (score 10):

In python re, you can span from numberic to upper case alpha. So..

```
import re
test = "01234ABCDEFGHIJKabcdefghijk01234abcdefghijkABCDEFGHIJK"
re.compile(r'[0-f]+').findall(test) # Bad: matches all uppercase alpha chars
## ['01234ABCDEFGHIJKabcdef', '01234abcdef', 'ABCDEFGHIJK']
re.compile(r'[0-F]+').findall(test) # Partial: does not match lowercase hex chars
## ['01234ABCDEF', '01234', 'ABCDEF']
re.compile(r'[0-F]+', re.I).findall(test) # Good
## ['01234ABCDEF', 'abcdef', '01234abcdef', 'ABCDEF']
re.compile(r'[0-f]+', re.I).findall(test) # Good
## ['01234ABCDEF', 'abcdef', '01234abcdef', 'ABCDEF']
re.compile(r'[0-Fa-f]+').findall(test) # Good (with uppercase-only magic)
## ['01234ABCDEF', 'abcdef', '01234abcdef', 'ABCDEF']
re.compile(r'[0-9a-fA-F]+').findall(test) # Good (with no magic)
## ['01234ABCDEF', 'abcdef', '01234abcdef', 'ABCDEF']
```

That makes the simplest Python UUID regex:

```
re_uuid = re.compile("[0-F]{8}-([0-F]{4}-){3}[0-F]{12}", re.I)
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to use timeit to compare the performance of these.

Enjoy.
Keep it Pythonic™!

**NOTE:** Those spans will also match `:;<=>?@'` so, if you suspect that could give you false positives, don't take the shortcut. (Thank you Oliver Aubert for pointing that out in the comments.)

Comment: [0-F] will indeed match 0-9 and A-F, but also any character whose ASCII code is between 57 (for 9) and 65 (for A), that is to say any of :;<=>?@'.

Comment: So do no use the abovementionned code except if you want to consider :=>;?<;:-<@=:-@=;=-@;@:->==@?>=:?=@; as a valid UUID :-)

Answer (score 9):

By definition, a UUID is 32 hexadecimal digits, separated in 5 groups by hyphens, just as you have described.  You shouldn't miss any with your regular expression.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Definition

Comment: Not correct.  RFC4122 only allows [1-5] for the version digit, and [89aAbB] for the variant digit.

Answer (score 9):

If using POSIX regex (`grep -E`, MySQL, etc.), this may be easier to read & remember:

```
[[:xdigit:]]{8}(-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}
```

Perl & PCRE flavours also support POSIX character classes so that'll work with them. For those, change the `(…)` to a non-capturing subgroup `(?:…)`.

JavaScript (and other syntaxes that support Unicode properties) can use a similarly legible version:

```js
/\p{Hex_Digit}{8}(?:-\p{Hex_Digit}{4}){3}-\p{Hex_Digit}{12}/u
```

Comment: imo, this is the best answer as it uses the appropriate character class and repeats the 4+'-' pattern three times with the quantifier {3}.  I wish this received a higher priority in the list of a responses.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the working REGEX: https://www.regextester.com/99148

```
const regex = [0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}
```

Answer (score 7):

So, I think Richard Bronosky actually has the best answer to date, but I think you can do a bit to make it somewhat simpler (or at least terser):

```
re_uuid = re.compile(r'[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}', re.I)
```

Comment: Even terser: `re_uuid = re.compile(r'[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){4}[0-9a-f]{8}', re.I)`

Comment: If you're looking to use capture groups to actually capture data out of a string, using this is NOT a great idea. It looks a little simpler, but complicates some usages.

Answer (score 6):

Variant for C++:

```
#include <regex>  // Required include

...

// Source string    
std::wstring srcStr = L"String with GIUD: {4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} any text";

// Regex and match
std::wsmatch match;
std::wregex rx(L"(\\{[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}\\})", std::regex_constants::icase);

// Search
std::regex_search(srcStr, match, rx);

// Result
std::wstring strGUID       = match[1];
```

Answer (score 6):

For UUID generated on OS X with `uuidgen`, the regex pattern is

```
[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-4[A-F0-9]{3}-[89AB][A-F0-9]{3}-[A-F0-9]{12}
```

Verify with

```
uuidgen | grep -E "[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-4[A-F0-9]{3}-[89AB][A-F0-9]{3}-[A-F0-9]{12}"
```

Answer (score 4):

For bash:

```
grep -E "[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}"
```

For example:

```
$> echo "f2575e6a-9bce-49e7-ae7c-bff6b555bda4" | grep -E "[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}"
f2575e6a-9bce-49e7-ae7c-bff6b555bda4
```

Comment: You need to include grep's `-i` option for case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 3):

```
$UUID_RE = join '-', map { "[0-9a-f]{$_}" } 8, 4, 4, 4, 12;
```

BTW, allowing only 4 on one of the positions is only valid for UUIDv4.
But v4 is not the only UUID version that exists.
I have met v1 in my practice as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to share the smallest regexp way to do the same of the good answers here.

`^[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){3}-[a-f\d]{12}$`

Please use with ignore case flag `i` for ignore case / case unsensitive:

```js
const pattern = /^[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){3}-[a-f\d]{12}$/i // JavaScript
```

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"^[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){3}-[a-f\d]{12}$", re.IGNORECASE) # Python
```

```php
$pattern = '/^[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){3}-[a-f\d]{12}$/i' // php
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't match certains UUID, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/a5b106b7f37b).

Comment: @Amine KOUIS Sorry, my bad, I forgot to add `^` at the start, anyway `^` at the start and `$` at the end means the start and the end of the string, if you remove the last `$` in you link, **it catches the first one, because the second is invalid, have non hex characters**.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give my contribution, as my regex cover all cases from OP and correctly group all relevant data on the group method (you don't need to post process the string to get each part of the uuid, this regex already get it for you)

```
([\d\w]{8})-?([\d\w]{4})-?([\d\w]{4})-?([\d\w]{4})-?([\d\w]{12})|[{0x]*([\d\w]{8})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{4})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{4})[0x, {]{5}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})[0x, ]{4}([\d\w]{2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Official [uuid library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) uses following regex:

```
/^(?:[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)$/i
```

See [reference](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/main/src/regex.js)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a brief regex to match a valid UUID: `/[\w]{8}(-[\w]{4}){3}-[\w]{12}/i` that works in most regex engine:

Don't forget to use with ignore case flag i for ignore case / case unsensitive:

**JavaScript:**

```
const pattern = /[\w]{8}(-[\w]{4}){3}-[\w]{12}/i
```

**Python:**

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[\w]{8}(-[\w]{4}){3}-[\w]{12}", re.IGNORECASE)
```

**PHP:**

```
$pattern = '/[\w]{8}(-[\w]{4}){3}-[\w]{12}/i'
```

[Regex DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/bfb1eaf4a4a6).