# Optimal UUID RegEx with optional delimeters

Tags: regex, uuid

I have already found a question for UUID regular expressions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex), but these expressions do not account missing delimeters.

I have come up with the [following expression](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5Cb(%5B0-9a-f%5D%7B8%7D-%3F(%5B0-9a-f%5D%7B4%7D-%3F)%7B3%7D%5B0-9a-f%5D%7B12%7D)%5Cb&input=foo%7Cbar%3Af81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6%7Cbaz), but is there a more optimal RegEx?

`/\b([0-9a-f]{8}-?([0-9a-f]{4}-?){3}[0-9a-f]{12})\b/i`

Comment: Optimal in term of what? Length? Execution time? A stricter regex?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by optimal that you mean a shorter expression.  I simplified your regex down to the following:

`/[\da-f]{8}-?([\da-f]{4}-?){3}[\da-f]{12}/i`, which you can see in action [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5B%5Cda-f%5D%7B8%7D-%3F%28%5B%5Cda-f%5D%7B4%7D-%3F%29%7B3%7D%5B%5Cda-f%5D%7B12%7D&input=foo%7Cbar%3Af81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6%7Cbaz%0A%0Aca761232ed4211cebacd00aa0057b223%0A%0ACA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223%0A%0AAb761232-fd42-11cE-BdAc-00Ff0057c223%0A%0A%7BCA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223%7D%0A%0A%28CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223%29).

I removed the outer parentheses and `\b` because everything was correctly matched without them.
I was also able to shave three characters off by replacing `[0-9a-f]` with `[\da-f]`.

I originally had `[0-F]`, but after examining the ASCII sequence, I realized that matched
`0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEF`, which includes some extra symbols that we do not want to match.

In conclusion, my expression is synonymous with yours but contains nine fewer characters.