# How do I extract a UUID from a string when the general format of the string is unknown?

Tags: php, uuid, string-matching

I’m working on a PHP script in which the format one of the strings I’m getting as input is unknown. For example, I may get the input:

```
user Name <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39
```

Or I could get the input:

```
7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39
```

My issue if the string comes in like this:

```
user Name <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39
```

How do I remove `user Name <` so all I’m left with is the UUID?

Now, what’s making this even harder is the UUID is never the same and 
`user Name <` will always have a different name.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you just need: `echo substr($str, strpos($str, "<")+1);` ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest solution is that you can just strip off everything before the first ocurrence of '<'. i've substituted 'name' here with two different sample names to illustrate:

```
<?php

$name1 = "user Michael <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39";
$name2 = "user Jasvinder <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39";

print substr($name1, strpos($name1, "<")+1);
print substr($name2, strpos($name2, "<")+1);
```

note, though, that if the "Name" field contains "<", there will be difficulties.

**edit**
now that you've accepted this as the solution, id' like to change it something better:

```
<?php

$name1 = "user Michael <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39";
$name2 = "user Jasvinder <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39";
$name3 = "7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39";

print preg_replace("/^.*\</","",$name1);
print preg_replace("/^.*\</","",$name2);
print preg_replace("/^.*\</","",$name3);
```

this handles both cases which the previous one, as was pointed out, didn't

Comment: It doesn't handle the other case specified in the question and is overall not very defensive (strips the first character or the code if there is no user name).

Comment: adding this helped if (strpos($ss, '<') !== FALSE)

Comment: @GolezTrol good catch. i've modified my response to use preg_replace to catch both cases. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like one of the few legitimate uses of regular expressions. After writing a regular expression to match UUIDs (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12843265)), you can throw your string into [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match), and if there are any UUIDs in it, it will find them and you can extract them.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `strpos` and `substr`. `strpos` returns the index of a character or `false` if it is not found. That way, you can leave the string untouched if it doesn't contain an `<`.

Note that you need a strict comparison operator (`===` or `!==`) when checking for `false`, because the string may contain a `<` in position `0`.=, which would also evaluate to false (or vice versa) when compared using normal comparison operators (`==`, `!=`).

```
<?php
$x = 'user Name <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39';

// Find the position of the `<`.
$p = strpos($x, '<');

// If that character exists, copy only the part after it.   
if ($p !== false) {
  $x = substr($x, $p+1);
}

echo $x;
```

You can easily make a function out of this so you can call it from anywhere. And as you can see it handles cases for different user names, or just a code without a user name at all:

```
<?php
function getUserId($input) {
  $p = strpos($input, '<');

  if ($p !== false) {
    $input = substr($input, $p+1);
  }
  return $input;
}

echo getUserId('user Name <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39') . '<br>';
echo getUserId('user Longer Name <7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39') . '<br>';
echo getUserId('7a240011-1b54-4a91-be27-a5cf8f474a39') . '<br>'a;
```