# Regex check for alphanumeric and length between '-'

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to do a regex check for an alphanumeric string that takes the following format:

> 45fe47hu-f8b9-40ef-c30b-b07fdb726a9e

so i need to check that the string is alphanumeric and follows the format `8-4-4-4-12`.

Am currently using

```
preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $string)
```

to test for alphanumeric but not sure how to check the length of the values between hyphens.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191078/3832970).

Comment: What is this 45fe47`hu` ?

Comment: `(\S{8}-)(\S{4}-){3}(\S{12})`