# Validating TimeUuid using JavaScript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid, timeuuid

I would like to validate a uuid string to make sure it's a valid time uuid (i.e. a test to check if a string is a time uuid).

For example: A request comes in with an id like so, as a string: `54d890dc-40a5-4686-8d7e-095e3934d99e` (this is uuid v4), is there any way to test whether this uuid is a time uuid (v1) or not (uuid v4)?

Comment: Use regexp as described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp :

**For example**

```
const index = [
    // UUID v1:
    /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[1][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i

    // UUID v2:
    /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[2][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i

    // UUID v3:
    /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[3][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i

    // UUID v4:
    /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[4][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i

   //UUID v5:
   /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[5][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i
].findIndex(x => x.test(stringToTest));

console.log(index === -1 ? 'Unknown UUID' : `UUID version ${index + 1}`);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex) about UUID regexp