# Regular expression extractor in js body JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to use Regular expression extractor to extract data from HTML body, but I'm new at Regular expression and I don't really understand how it works.

I want to extract `bb079382-e3e3-430d-a34e-18a406bb5419` value from `rfb.connect("beta.anatobrace.com", port, "bb079382-e3e3-430d-a34e-18a406bb5419", path);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex

Comment: @Learner not duplicate because it search value from specific pattern inside javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include alphanumeric and dash character after port, in your case:

```
beta.anatobrace.com", port, "([\-\w]+)
```

Of course use Template `$1$` and Match No. `1`

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what i need !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel comfortable enough with Regular Expressions you can almost always go for [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) instead. In basically extracts what it will find between the "Left Boundary" and the "Right Boundary" so if you set:

- Left Boundary: `rfb.connect("beta.anatobrace.com", port, "`
- Right Boundary: `", path);`

You will get your ID in between.

[image: Boundary Extractor Demo]

Moreover, Boundary Extractor consumes less resources so you will be able to simulate more virtual user from a single machine comparing to using Regular Expressions Extractor. See [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) article for more details.