# How to remove some parts of a string?

Tags: java, regex

I have to remove some parts of a string like this:

```
customers/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000111/areas/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000222/orders/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000555/invoices/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000777/employees/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000213.gz
```

To get the path without the uuids but with the file extension. It should look like

`customers/areas/orders/invoices/employees/.gz`

How can I do this? With Matcher or substring? Which is best option? Is there any custom regex that I can use to remove UUIDs from the string?

Comment: How do you get those paths? Are they always the same? What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: Regexp replace should work, give it a try!

Comment: some good UUID regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that UUID in your case are only numbers with minus You can use a regular expression like the following

```
[0-9][-0-9]*[0-9][\/]?
```

to replace strings like

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000111/
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000222/
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000555/
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000213
...
```

with an empty string as in the following code:

```
String path = ...;
// Note the additional \ in the following string, 
// this is necessary because we are using a string to represent the regexp
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("[0-9][-0-9]*[0-9][\\/]?", ""));
```

that prints

```
customers/areas/orders/invoices/employees/.gz
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanx

Comment: @AdamJungen if your uuid are in hexadecimal format you have to replace each 0-9 with 0-9A-Fa-f

Comment: No it is not, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the string using the following Regex:

```
(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try **FilenameUtils.getExtension** from **Apache Commons IO**

(you may specify either full path or just file name):

```
String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("customers/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000111/areas/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000222/orders/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000555/invoices/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000777/employees/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000213.gz"); // returns "gz"
String ext2 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("002345620000000213.txt"); // returns "txt"
```