# Extract groups with regex and construct URL in a single line

Tags: c#, regex, url

I am currently trying to extract values from a string and construct a URL that includes those values. I went through a dozen regex question, but I am not quite satisfied with the answers.

I have custom encoded strings with more than one information and I want to construct a new URL that contains those information.

For example `35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8|Master` should become `http://my-server/media/guid/35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8?v=Master`. My first assumption was

```cs
var input = "35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8|Master"
var pattern = @"((?:[a-f0-9]+-?){5})|(\w+)"
var replacement = "http://my-server/media/guid/$1?v=$2"
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement)
```

However this replaces each group with the full URL. Limitation is, that I am not aware of `input`, `pattern`, `replacement` or `output`. `pattern` and `replacement` are two config values and I don't want to make it x pairs of config values, `input` comes from somewhere else in the application and could have any custom encoding (pipe, colon, ...) `output` depends on the use case. It can have any number of groups in the pattern and doesn't even have to be a URL in the end.

I can think of different ways to do this, like parsing the string myself, or trying to create a replacement dictionary, or using regex to find the groups and then string replace for `$1` => match.Groups[0]. I just feel like there must be an obvious 1-liner solution for that in .NET since I even remember doing that in PHP.

**Answer**: It's not a .NET limitation, it was simply the unescaped pipe.

Comment: Pehaps split on a pipe and use the 2 parts to assemble the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `(([a-f0-9]+-?){5})|\w+` the second group should be capturing the word characters after the pipe (escape the pipe to match it literally).

If you repeat this part `([a-f0-9]+-?)` 5 times, the match could also end on a hyphen.

To match the values separated by the dash, you could match the character class `[a-f0-9]+` and repeat matching that `{4}` times prepended by a `-`

```
([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+){4})\|(\w+)
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5ba-f0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a-%5ba-f0-9%5d%2b%29%7b4%7d%29%5c%7c%28%5cw%2b%29&i=35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8%7cMaster&r=http%3a%2f%2fmy-server%2fmedia%2fguid%2f%241%3fv%3d%242) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/pIBWoS)

[image]

```
var input = "35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8|Master";
var pattern = @"([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+){4})\|(\w+)";
var replacement = "http://my-server/media/guid/$1?v=$2";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Result

```
http://my-server/media/guid/35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8?v=Master
```

Comment: I'll be damned - my mistake was not escaping the damn pipe from my example. Thanks, I just spent 30min researching Regex.Replace docs and SO.

Comment: In the first version of your pattern the second capturing group was not at the right place as well and the pattern would also match ending on a `-`.

Comment: Yes, those were from creating an abstract SO question, BUT the real error was the unescaped pipe. I edited my question but left the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This expression might also work here:

```
^(\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b)\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hSdsBM/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b)\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*$";
        string substitution = @"http://my-server/media/guid/\1?v=$2";
        string input = @"35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8|Master
35afe06d-8393-4559-b6d7-74d35ce131d8|  Master  ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

#### Reference

[Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)