# how to regex that kind of string

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.7.2

I want regex that string, but I really dont know how. I have figured out how I can get the numbers, but not the other strings

```
string text = "1cb07348-34a4-4741-b50f-c41e584370f7 Youtuber https://youtube.com/lol love youtube";
```

```
string regexstring = "[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]*(?<id>)"
```

**code**

```
Match m = Regex.Match(text, regexstring);
if(m.Success)
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);
```

Output

```
1cb07348-34a4-4741-b50f-c41e584370f7
```

now I want that the output is that

```
1cb07348-34a4-4741-b50f-c41e584370f7
Youtuber
https://youtube.com/lol
love youtube
```

what I finished is the first line of the output but I dont know how to regex the other strings

Comment: can you  clarify, what exactly you want? Make every word separated by space separated by newline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([\w]+-){5}` is cleaner to replace what you already did.

`\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Then, if your string always has a website preceded and followed by a number of words separated by spaces, you can do this:

```
string regexstring = "((\w*-){4})(\w*) (.+?)[A-Za-z]?(https://[^ ]+?) (.+)";
```

**Ouput**

```
Match m = Regex.Match(text, regexstring);
if(m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1] + "" + m.Groups[2] + "" + m.Groups[3] + "\n" + m.Groups[4] + "\n" + m.Groups[5] + "\n" + m.Groups[6]);
```

Comment: hey the match in this example is not success

Comment: could you test it out

Comment: @newcoma Whoops sorry. Try that.

Comment: Oh I thought that was a typo because it wasn't in your original output. Where do you want the `V`?

Comment: I really dont know why they add there a char in `Vhttps://` so I want only `https://` without the char so just remove

Comment: sometimes the char is there but sometimes not do I need to make it like this `?[A-z]`

Comment: Yeah but put the question mark after the [A-z] and leave it out of the parentheses so it isn't included in the group. I updated answer for good measure.

Comment: Updated. Try again.

Comment: great I really thanxs you for helping me out have a nice weekend

Comment: My pleasure. You too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that, if our inputs would look like the same, this expression might be somewhat close to what you might have in mind, not sure though:

```
^(\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b)\s+(.*?)\s+[A-Z](https?:\/\/\S+)\s+(.*)$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9PqDLj/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/9PqDLj/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Reference

[Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)

Comment: I dont understand the result of this the output is the same as the input