# Django urls with UUID issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Initial Error :  When CustomerID was **CharField** in models.py :

[image: Error Message :]

after making changes to the model and making the CustomerID **UUIDField** getting the below error :

[image]

I am trying to redirect to the view based on the CustomerID but its not working for UUIDs. 
It was previously working fine with integers.

Please suggest.

url.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
   path('<uuid:customer_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
   path('search/customers/<uuid:customer_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
   path('customers/<uuid:customer_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
   path('edit/<uuid:customer_id>', views.edit, name='edit'),
   path('modify/<uuid:customer_id>', views.modify, name='modify'),
]
```

views.py

```
 @login_required
 def detail(request, customer_id):
     customer = get_object_or_404(CustomerMaster, pk=customer_id)
     return render(request, 'customers/detail.html',{'customer':customer})
```

models.py

```
   class CustomerMaster(models.Model):
         customerid = models.UUIDField(db_column='CustomerID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
         customernumber = models.CharField(db_column='CustomerNumber', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
         customername = models.CharField(db_column='CustomerName', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
          lastmodifiedutc = models.DateTimeField(db_column='LastModifiedUTC')  # Field name made lowercase.
          lastmodifiedby = models.CharField(db_column='LastModifiedBy', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
          active = models.BooleanField(db_column='Active')  # Field name made lowercase.
         customershortname = models.CharField(db_column='CustomerShortName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


      class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'Customer_Master'

            def __str__(self):
                return self.CustomerName
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant models?

Comment: @wfehr I have updated with the model. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The letters in the UUID must be lowercase according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

> **uuid** - Matches a formatted UUID. To prevent multiple URLs from mapping to the same page, dashes must be included and letters must be lowercase. For example, **075194d3-6885-417e-a8a8-6c931e272f00**. Returns a **UUID** instance.

Comment: entries in the database are in CAPS.. not sure how to handle lower case UUIDs in that case.

Comment: You are using a UUIDField, which handles transformation of UUID to/from the db representation.  In other words, how you see the value in the db is not necessarily how the value is handled once in django land.

Comment: @monkut - thanks for your input. In that case, how do i transform lowercase to Uppercase in  the view.py detail method when doing a get ? Please see my error screenshots above.

Comment: Please don't add new questions by editing your original one. Your initial issue was the regex mismatch. I suggest you to post the new issue as another question.

Comment: this is not a new question... I did the modification and still stuck on the same issue "Django urls with UUID issue"

Answer (score 0):

For the `UUIDField` looks like you are using Microsoft SQLServer database that does not support the UUIDField properly....

So if you use `CharField` you probably want to introduce a regex UUID check on the incoming uuid field checkout this:

[Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)

As mentioned you want to make sure that the DB value is consistent so using `.lower()` on the validated input would be a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by making the CustomerID as CharField and passing string parameter in the URL.

Comment: don't post an answer with "solved it via ..." but rather mark an answer as accepted if it helped you.