# Need help in regex function in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I've below sample text in a text file and wanted to get the value after id to be captured in a variable for later use.

```
id                          : 42cdb643-0a11-416b-b66b-7bb28a9a20ea
isReadOnly                  : False
somestring                   : False
somestring                   : {}
name                        : 

id                          : d006d69e-8d04-48d7-8806-cdc39c18e679
somestring                  : False
somestring                  : False
somestring                  : 822F0340-818A-4F23-AA78-633B6436913F
upstreamDataflowsOfDatasets : {}
```

I have the same set of data in the text file. I'm looking for a PowerShell code which will scan the text and return value for id as `42cdb643-0a11-416b-b66b-7bb28a9a20ea` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the `id` property values from your text file, use a relatively simple regex with the `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
Select-String '^id\s+:\s+(.*)' File.txt | foreach { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

With your sample text, this yields (an array of `[string]`s):

```
42cdb643-0a11-416b-b66b-7bb28a9a20ea
d006d69e-8d04-48d7-8806-cdc39c18e679
```

Explanation:

- Regex `^id\s+:\s+(.*)` finds lines that start with (`^`) string `id`, followed by one or more whitespace chars. (`\s+`), a `:` and more whitespace, and captures whatever remains on the line (`.*`) in a capture group (`(...)`).
- `Select-String` passes only matching lines through.
- The `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) command accesses the details of the regex match (`$_.Matches`), whose `.Groups` property contains the capture-group matches; index `[1]` is the first (and only) capture group's match, and its `.Value` property contains the matched text, which is the ID of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
\bid\s+:\s*\b([0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12})\b
```

would probably work OK, and your desired id value is in the capturing group `$1`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FaogIp/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FaogIp/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/FaogIp/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [`Source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6640851/6553328)