# Extract string matching a specific format

Tags: regex, string, qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

Given a QString, I want to extract a substring from the main string input.

e.g. I have a QString reading something like:

```
\\\\?\\Volume{db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963}\\
```

I need to extract the string (if a string with the format exists) using a template/format matching a regex format `(\w){8}([-](\w){4}){3}[-](\w){12}` as shown below:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and it should return

```
db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963
```

if found, else an empty `QString`.

Currently, I can achieve this by doing something like:

```
string.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("\\", "").replace("?", "").replace("Volume", "");
```

But this is tedious and inefficient, and tailored to a specific request.

Is there a generalized function that enables me to extract a substring using a regex format or other?

**Update**

To clarity after @Emma's answer, I want e.g. `QString::extract("(\w){8}([-](\w){4}){3}[-](\w){12}")` which returns `db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bunch of ways to extract part of a string as presented in the question.  I don't know how much of the string format is fixed vs. variable, so possibly not all of these examples would be practical. Also some examples below are using [`QStringRef`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringref.html#details) class which can be more efficient but must have the original string (the one being referenced) available while any references are active (see warning in docs).

```cpp
  const QString str("\\\\?\\Volume{db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963}\\");

  // Treat str as a list delimited by "{" and "}" chars.

  const QString sectResult = str.section('{', 1, 1).section('}', 0, 0);  // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"
  const QString sectRxResult = str.section(QRegExp("\\{|\\}"), 1, 1);    // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"

  // Example using QStringRef, though this could also be just QString::split() which returns QString copies.
  const QVector<QStringRef> splitRef = str.splitRef(QRegExp("\\{|\\}"));
  const QStringRef splitRefResult = splitRef.value(1);  // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"

  // Use regular expressions to find/extract matching string

  const QRegularExpression rx("\\w{8}(?:-(\\w){4}){3}-\\w{12}");  // match a UUID string
  const QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx.match(str);
  const QString rxResultStr = match.captured(0);        // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"
  const QStringRef rxResultRef = match.capturedRef(0);  // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"

  const QRegularExpression rx2(".+\\{([^{\\}]+)\\}.+");  // capture anything inside { } brackets
  const QRegularExpressionMatch match2 = rx2.match(str);
  const QString rx2ResultStr = match2.captured(1);       // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"
  // Make a copy for replace so that our references to the original string remain valid.
  const QString replaceResult = QString(str).replace(rx2, "\\1");   // = "db41aa6a-c0b8-11e9-bc8a-806e6f6e6963"

  qDebug() << sectResult << sectRxResult << splitRefResult << rxResultStr
           << rxResultRef << rx2ResultStr << replaceResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
Volume{(\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b)}
```

or just,

```
\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b
```

for a full match might be a bit closer.

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/e47l2b/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/e47l2b/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Source

[Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)

Comment: the regex is fine, I don't have a problem with the regex. I am looking for an efficient way of extracting a substring matching a regex from another string.