# How to check ramsey/uuid requirements with a regex?

Tags: regex, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a symfony 5 project.

I use ramsey/uuid.

My doctrine.yaml

```
 dbal:
     types:
         uuid: Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidType
```

My route in my controller

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/job/{id}",
 *     name="job_show",
 *     methods={"GET"}
 * )
 */
```

I would like to add the requirements to verify if the "id" parameter is a uuid.

I tried with several regex but none work :

Regex tried :

```
requirements={"id"="/^[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-4[a-f0-9]{3}\-[a-f0-9]{4​}\-[a-f0-9]{12}$/"}
```

```
requirements={"id"="/^[a-f0-9\-]{36}$/"}
```

Every time I get this error:

> No route found for "GET /job/dc5a945c-25a1-4760-bd69-970d94560cce"

I have watch severals similar questions like [Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex) but none helped me.

Does anyone know where my error may come from or how to do it differently ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
requirements={"id"="[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}"})
```

Or, as of Symfony 6.1, you can use predefined route requirements:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Requirement\Requirement;

#[Route('/job/{id}',
    name: 'job_show',
    requirements: ['id' => Requirement::UUID_V6]
)]
```

Check the feature introduction on the [Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-improved-routing-requirements-and-utf-8-parameters#a-collection-of-common-routing-requirements).

Comment: Thank you it works !  However I tried it too but I think I wrote it wrong :)