# Regex search for UUID based uri in splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

I am trying to search for all events which contain a UUID as part of a request url. Here is my query:

```
.... | regex requestURI=*/employee/[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}*
```

It gives error as:

```
Unknown search command '0'
```

What's the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using " instead of *

```
.... | regex requestURI="/employee/[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}"
```

Now talking about the regex itself, but there is already a question for that. Check the answers here for the RegEx: [Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)
Some important points like case sensitivity etc. are discussed there.