# How to validate property field which is UUID in json schema?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

```
   {
  "status": 200,
  "id": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",
  "shop": {
    "c73bcdcc-2669-4bf6-81d3-e4ae73fb11fd": {
      "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655443210": {
        "quantity": {
          "value": 10
        }
      },
      "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655443211": {
        "quantity": {
          "value": 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my json response. I want to validate the fields "c73bcdcc-2669-4bf6-81d3-e4ae73fb11fd" , "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655443210" and "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655443211", which are uniquely generated every time whenever hits the endpoint.

Comment: Is shop an array on an object? if the shop is an object it has just 2 property or it is dynamic too?

Comment: @behrad it is like shop having "c73bcdcc-2669-4bf6-81d3-e4ae73fb11fd" as a shopId , "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655443210" and "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655443211" are the variants of shopId. shop is an object having only one shopId but shopId has variants as many as we want.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @pxcv7r's answer:

> To validate UUID in particular, you may use format in JSON schema, which provides built-in support for the UUID syntax: { "type": "string", "format": "uuid" }
>
> See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html

Additionally, you can use a combination of [`"propertyNames"`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names) and [`"unevaluatedProperties"`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#unevaluated-properties) to avoid the need for any regular expression:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "status": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uuid"
    },
    "shop": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1,
      "maxProperties": 1,
      "propertyNames": {
        "format": "uuid"
      },
      "unevaluatedProperties": {
        "type":"object",
        "minProperties": 1,
        "propertyNames": {
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "unevaluatedProperties": {
          "title": "single variant of a shop",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "quantity": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate in JSON schema that a string conforms to a regular expression pattern use
`{ "type": "string", "pattern": "\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b" }`

The concrete pattern is adapted from the question [Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex;) see there for more details.

To validate UUID in particular, you may use `format` in JSON schema, which provides built-in support for the UUID syntax: `{ "type": "string", "format": "uuid" }`

See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html

Comment: {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "status", "id", "shop" ],
    "properties": {
        "status": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "shop": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "c73bcdcc-2669-4bf6-81d3-e4ae73fb11fd"
            ], "properties": {"c73bcdcc-2669-4bf6-81d3-e4ae73fb11fd": { ..
 instead of "c73bcdcc-2669-4bf6-81d3-e4ae73fb11fd" what code should i place in required[] and in properties ?

Answer (score 0):

You need "patternProperties":

```
{ 
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "shop":{
      "type":"object",
      "additionalProperties":false,
      "patternProperties":{
        "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}": {
          "type":"object",
          "patternProperties" :{
            "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}":{
              "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                 "quantity":{
                   "type":"object",
                   "properties":{
                     "value":{
                       "type":"integer"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Viewes in JSONBuddy]