# Regular expression to extract shift number from customer message

Tags: regex

I need to take out shift id from text using regular expressions to provide correct payment. We have 3 types of messages from customer to our system:

```
1)Payment for shift # edc5df26-ad62-4685-ad80-4a3a60118479 receipt number #12345
2)Payment for shift # 394e3027-be5d-4369-91e6-88437c5330e0, adress: Germany, Frankfurt..
3)Payment for job shift # c921e015-74b2-4df2-84b2-e546a636272f
```

So the result should be:

```
1)'edc5df26-ad62-4685-ad80-4a3a60118479'
2)'394e3027-be5d-4369-91e6-88437c5330e0'
3)'c921e015-74b2-4df2-84b2-e546a636272f'
```

which can end rather with space symbol, comma, or be the end of message.

So I can only takte all symbols after # using:
`(?<=#).*`

But have no idea what to do next. What regular expression can solve the issue?

Comment: What is the logic for your #1 result to *not* include `12345`?

Comment: Because we need only shift number,   all symbols after it are  about receipt number which we don't need to extract.

Comment: And how is a *program* supposed to know that?

Comment: Because we need only first expression following # symbol. We don't care if it shows up again.

Comment: How.  Is.  The.  Program.  Supposed.  To.  Know.  That?

Comment: Which program? I don't get whay you mean.  On next ster we use extracted 'edc5df26-ad62-4685-ad80-4a3a60118479' as id in shifts datasets to get more details about payment. Thats why we are extracting. 
The problem is that the message come from clients who can writhe payment description in any form they want and somehow mention this very shift id, thats why we have to extract it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)

Comment: Alternatively `/Payment for (?:job )?shift # ([a-f0-9-]+)/` ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/HD0E2I/1)) is pretty simple. Please add to the question whatever you've tried.

Comment: This is a very clear question with example data, expected results and what the OP tried to get the matches.

Comment: use regex101.com and look at bottom right. Hint look into lookaheads/lookbehinds

Answer (score 2):

You could assert `shift #`  to the left, and then match the range of allowed characters followed by repeating the hyphen at least 1 or more times.

```
(?<=\bshift # )[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQsnpO/1).

Answer (score 0):

Right after you matched the # symbol, you can start capturing your shift ID with this regex for example:

```
(?<=#)\s([a-z-\d]+)
```

- **\s**: to match the whitespace character
- **()**: to capture your id
- **[a-z-\d]**: to match any lowcase character, hyphen and digit

Comment: Thanks, it solves most of the issue, but if we use it on first example, it takes #12345
as well. We need only first occurance of expression after '#' symbol

Comment: In your example you have a space between the # symbol and the Shift id, so it doesn't match with #12345. However, if it turns out that there is no space, the regex contains parentheses that allow you to extract only the first group and therefore ignore the following matches, including receipt number #12345