# Ansible : regex_replace throws "could not be converted to an dict" error

Tags: ansible, uuid

I am using `ansible-playboo`k to run a command which uses `expect` on the Remote Server.

```yaml
- name: Restore Database
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /opt/python/bin/python
  expect:
    timeout: 60
    command: "odacli irestore-database -r /tmp/bm_{{server}}_{{item}}_backupreport.json {{bkpcfg_name_var}} {{bkpcfg_rmanpass_var}} {{dbHome_var}}"
    responses:
      "Enter SYS user password: " : "{{provision_password}}"
      "Retype SYS user password: " : "{{provision_password}}"
      "Enter RMAN backup encryption password: " : "{{rmanbkupPassword}}"
      "Do you want to provide another RMAN backup encryption password.*: " : "{{rman_passconf_var}}"
  register: command_output
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Print cmdout
  debug:
    msg: "{{command_output.stdout}}"
```

The `command_output.stdout` looks like this

```json
TASK [Print cmdout] ************************************************************************
ok: [abc.com] => {
    "msg": "Enter SYS user password: \r\nRetype SYS user password: \r\nEnter RMAN backup encryption password: \r\nDo you want to provide another RMAN backup encryption password? [y/n] (default 'n'): n\r\n{\r\n  \"jobId\" : \"94f95792-7de2-4401-a3c2-b09e31834770\",\r\n  \"status\" : \"Created\",\r\n  \"message\" : null,\r\n  \"reports\" : [ ],\r\n  \"createTimestamp\" : \"October 10, 2023 10:31:56 AM GMT\",\r\n  \"resourceList\" : [ ],\r\n  \"description\" : \"Database service recovery with db name: testdb1\",\r\n  \"updatedTime\" : \"October 10, 2023 10:31:56 AM GMT\",\r\n  \"jobType\" : null\r\n}"
}
```

Now, I am trying to remove a few lines from the output before converting it to a JSON object using the following code

```yaml
- name: Remove password lines from  job details  json file
  set_fact:
    jsondata: "{{ command_output.stdout | regex_replace('Enter SYS user password: ', '') | regex_replace('Retype SYS user password: ' , '') | regex_replace('Enter RMAN backup encryption password: ', '') | regex_replace('Do you want to provide another RMAN backup encryption password.*: ', '') | from_json }}"
  when : command_output.rc == 0
```

But I am getting the following error

```json
TASK [Remove password lines from  job details  json file] **********************************
fatal: [abc.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'jsondata': \"{{ command_output.stdout | regex_replace('Enter SYS user password: ', '') | regex_replace('Retype SYS user password: ' , '') | regex_replace('Enter RMAN backup encryption password: ', '') | regex_replace('Do you want to provide another RMAN backup encryption password.*: ', '') | from_json }}\"}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 6)\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/odacnr/playbooks/restoreDatabaseSub.yaml': line 99, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Remove password lines from  job details  json file\n      ^ here\n"}
```

This is the output without the filter

```json
ok: [abc.com] => {
    "msg": "\r\n\r\n\r\nn\r\n{\r\n  \"jobId\" : \"8c978d14-a3e9-4555-b323-877bdcc29b0c\",\r\n  \"status\" : \"Created\",\r\n  \"message\" : null,\r\n  \"reports\" : [ ],\r\n  \"createTimestamp\" : \"October 12, 2023 17:54:06 PM GMT\",\r\n  \"resourceList\" : [ ],\r\n  \"description\" : \"Database service recovery with db name: testdb1\",\r\n  \"updatedTime\" : \"October 12, 2023 17:54:06 PM GMT\",\r\n  \"jobType\" : null\r\n}"
}
```

I am looking to get only the `jobId` value from the above i.e. `8c978d14-a3e9-4555-b323-877bdcc29b0c` into a variable.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: You are obviously not producing a json output with your series of regex. Hence why `from_json`? Remove that filter to see if you get a correct output string. Morevorer, please [edit] and fix your yaml examples: none of them are valid (indentation errors) in your question so it is hard to know if it's a simple copy/paste error or if they can be the source or your problem. While you are at it, please sanitize your example. Expect has nothing to do with the problem. All is neede to reproduce is an input string, the operations to modify it, the current output and the one you expect instead.

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, I have corrected the examples with syntax, indentation etc. What I expect from the output would be a json only. But why the json is not valid after regex is a question here.  The inout string, output is all mentioned above. Please let me know if any other info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> ***I am looking to get only the `jobId` value ... into a variable.***

It seems your Use Case is simply [searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/). Therefore

```yaml
  - name: Show Job UUID
    debug:
      msg: "jobId: {{ command_output.stdout | regex_search('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}') }}"
```

will result into the required output.